# Change froala image param

Tags: froala

How we can change or access imageParam attribute in froala. I want to send dynamic param value while image upload.

```
$(element).froalaEditor({
              key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
              heightMin: 320,
              placeholderText: 'Create Beat here...',
              toolbarStickyOffset: 46,
              //toolbarTop: true,
              pastePlain: true,
              toolbarSticky: true,
              //toolbarInline: true,
              toolbarButtonsXS: ['insertImage','quote', 'insertVideo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', '|', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'insertHR', '|', 'insertLink', 'insertTable', 'fullscreen' ],
              toolbarButtonsSM: ['insertImage','quote', 'insertVideo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', '|', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'insertHR', '|', 'insertLink', 'insertTable', 'fullscreen' ],
              toolbarButtonsMD: ['insertImage','quote', 'insertVideo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', '|', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'insertHR', '|', 'insertLink', 'insertTable', 'fullscreen' ],
              toolbarButtons: ['insertImage','quote', 'insertVideo', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'undo', 'redo', '|', 'subscript', 'superscript', '|', 'paragraphStyle', 'paragraphFormat', 'align', '|', 'formatOL', 'formatUL', 'insertHR', '|', 'insertLink', 'insertTable', 'fullscreen' ],
              linkAlwaysNoFollow: false,
              imageUploadURL: '/apiv1/home/uploadPhoto',
              imageUploadParams: {
                id: id
              }
          })
```

Above code id is always null. I want it to change sometime later.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found it, Froala store all its param in 
editor.opts
and for image param
editor.opts.imageUploadParams